# Get variable from another method

Tags: java, string, methods

I'have a question about this script for a `Dice`. I wrote a method using `Math.random` and now I want to get result `String` in my program.

The button has to roll the dice.

So my method gooien is rolling the dice and gives me a number between 1 and 6.
The JButton is recalling this method to reroll the dice.

Now i want number that is being rerolled into a string.

```
// paneel met 3 tekstvakken
class dobbelsteentjes1 extends JPanel {
    private JButton gooien;

public dobbelsteentjes1(){

    gooien=new JButton ("Gooien");
    gooien.addActionListener(new gooienHandler());

    add(gooien);
}
//inwendige klasse
class gooienHandler implements ActionListener{

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    gooien();
}

}
    public void gooien(){
    double gooi1, gooi2,worp1;
    gooi1= Math.random();
    gooi2=Math.random();
    worp1=gooi1*6+1;
}

public void paintComponent ( Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent( g );
    g.drawString( "U heeft gegooid:" + worp1, 50, 30);
}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Im sorry, the variable + worp1 isnt working, it gives me a error. i think because its in another method.

Comment: You should also post the error and the output you expect.

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Explain your problem, this is not clear. Also, watch the indentation,

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the scope of program. You see in programming languages variables are scoped. Basically you have variable worp1 scoped only inside gooien() method. Nothing can see this variable outside of this method. What you can do is to declare worp1 inside your class like this:

```
 class dobbelsteentjes1 extends JPanel {
    private JButton gooien;
    double worp1 = 0;
```

then your method should look like this:

```
 public void gooien(){
    double gooi1, gooi2;
    gooi1= Math.random();
    gooi2=Math.random();
    worp1=gooi1*6+1;
}
```

And then you can use this variable inside `paintComponent`. In my example worp1 is properties of class, and it will be visible from every method which your class implements.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this is not wat i mean.

in my method worp1=gooi1*6+1
so it becomes a number between 1 and 6.

The JButton calls this method so the number changes, like a Dice. 

Now i want the number from the dice as a drawstring.

i hope you understand me in my bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

I think You want String type variable of Math.random();
So, Try this : String var1 = Math.random()+""; to  create string type variable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to  draw worp1's value in drawString method. But drawString method belongs to Java Graphics library.That means you can use it in two form;

```
drawString(AttributedCharacterIterator iterator, int x, int y);

drawString(String str, int x, int y);
```

(if you want to learn deeply here is source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html )

So , you have to convert you double value of warp1 parameter to String form like this : 
g.drawString( "U heeft gegooid:" + Double.toString(warp1) , 50, 30);

Hopefully it helps.